# lambda aws syntax error : missing ) after argument list

Tags: node.js, windows, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, syntax-error

```html
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'ap-southeast-1'})

exports.handler = async(event) => {
    //TODO implement
    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.queryStringParameters));
    const requestId = context.awsRequestId;
    await createMessage(requestId).then(() => {
        callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200, 
        body:  `
            <hl>query string parameters</hl>
            <p>${JSON.stringify(event.queryStringParameters)}</p>
            <p>one: ${obj.one}</p>
            <hr/>
            <hl>path</hl>
            <p>${JSON.stringify(event.requestContext.http.path)}</p>
            <hr/>
         `, 
       header: {
            'Content-Type' :  'text/html; charset=uft-8',
        },
    }
function createMessage(requestId) {
     const params = {
        TableName: 'Message',
        Item: {
            'Hello' : 'one'
        }
     }
    return ddb.put(params).promise();
};
```

Comment: what should i do next? (sorry for bad typing)

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
    await createMessage(requestId).then(() => {
        callback(null, {
```

open two sets of parentheses `(` that are not closed.

I highly recommend using a text editor (eg Visual Studio Code) that highlights parentheses to help identify these issues.

Comment: how to close these parenthese?

Comment: Put the `)` in the correct spots to finish what is being passed to the functions.

Comment: may can you write in "correct form" ? becuase i can't find it sorry...

Comment: It all depends on what you want your code to do! But every open bracket `(` needs to be matched with a close bracket `)`. This is basic syntax for programming languages.

Comment: thanks! there's no problem about bracket now!. but i get new error 'Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0' :)